# RealmSwift nested object getter not returning data

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am having some issues with my Realm object returning 0 when trying to access the property.

when I do:

```
    print(calculation)
    print(calculation.homePrice)
```

It gives me:

```
PaymentsCalculation {
    id = 90941762-E648-4377-ABA3-4BDA88880768;
    homePrice = 200000;
    downPayment = 40000;
    interestRate = 0.04;
    homeInsurance = 900;
    HOADues = 0;
    loanType = 30-year fixed;
    hidePMI = 0;
}
0.0
```

Why is this happening?

calculation is a nested object from `User` class:

```
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {
    var id: String = NSUUID().UUIDString

    let monthlyPayments = List<PaymentsCalculation>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh.

Forgot `dynamic` on that `homePrice`

In case anyone is having the same issue:

Remember to do this:

```
dynamic var homePrice: Double = 0.0
```